# Sqlalchemy upsert on conflict on postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert, upsert

I would ignore duplicte key when insert in postgres the data
my table has an unique constraint on 3 columns. Now the code I post below works just with primary_key but not with  unique  constraint. Someone has suggestions?
thanks
E

```
            @compiles(Insert)
            def _prefix_insert_with_ignore(insert_srt, compiler, **kw):

                conn = Connection()
                conn_str = conn.conn_str()
                test_conn = conn_str.find("sqlite")
                if test_conn == 0:
                    return compiler.visit_insert(insert_srt.prefix_with('OR IGNORE'), **kw)
                else:
                    #if the connection is postgresql
                    pk = insert_srt.table.primary_key
                    insert = compiler.visit_insert(insert_srt, **kw)
                    ondup = f"ON CONFLICT ({','.join(c.name for c in pk)}) DO NOTHING"
                    
                    upsert = ' '.join((insert, ondup))
                    return upsert
```

Comment: Would not the [INSERT…ON CONFLICT (Upsert)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert) be a solution for the `postgresql` version without even requiring a custom compile?

Comment: If you do need to support 2 different RDBMS and you do feel you need to implement custom compilation, I also suggest you use [Dialect-specific compilation rules](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/compiler.html#dialect-specific-compilation-rules)

Comment: I tried to do this
uk=insert_srt.table.constraints
ondup = f"ON CONFLICT ({','.join(str(c.colums) for c in uc)}) DO NOTHING". I have the list of unique constraint and primary key constraint. So I need just the unique constraint columns. How I can do?

Comment: You might want something like `c = next(x for x in products.constraints if isinstance(x, sa.UniqueConstraint))` and `column_names = [col.name for col in c.columns]`?

Comment: You're welcome.  I would review the links provided by van though...

Answer (score 0):

Ok this works well for me

thanks very much @snakechrmerb

```
            @compiles(Insert)
            def _prefix_insert_with_ignore(insert_srt, compiler, **kw):

                conn = Connection()
                conn_str = conn.conn_str()
                test_conn = conn_str.find("sqlite")
                if test_conn == 0:
                    return compiler.visit_insert(insert_srt.prefix_with('OR IGNORE'), **kw)
                else:
                    #if the connection is postgresql
                    ck = insert_srt.table.constraints
                    pk = insert_srt.table.primary_key
                    insert = compiler.visit_insert(insert_srt, **kw)
                    c = next(x for x in ck if isinstance(x, sa.UniqueConstraint))
                    column_names = [col.name for col in c.columns]
                    s= ", ".join(column_names)
                    ondup = f'ON CONFLICT ({s})DO NOTHING'
                
                    upsert = ' '.join((insert, ondup))
                    return upsert
```